# Accessing Windows system variables in Java 1.4

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables, java1.4

What is the best/foolproof way to get the values of environment variables in Windows when using J2SE 1.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have definitely no way to access environment variables straigthly from java API. The only way to achieve that with Runtime.exec with such a code :

```
Process p = null;
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
// System.out.println(OS);
if (OS.indexOf("windows 9") > -1) {
  p = r.exec( "command.com /c set" );
}
else if ( (OS.indexOf("nt") > -1)
       || (OS.indexOf("windows 2000") > -1 )
       || (OS.indexOf("windows xp") > -1) ) {
  // thanks to JuanFran for the xp fix!
  p = r.exec( "cmd.exe /c set" );
}
```

Although you can access Java variables thanks to System.getProperties();
But you would only get some env variables mapped by JVM itself, and additional data you could provide on java command line with "-Dkey=value"

For more information see http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0150.html

Comment: This is helpful.. I just used echo %env_variable_name% to get the value directly, instead of having to parse the output of SET.

Comment: This won't help you find the environment variables set on the running java program if they're different from the global set of environment varaibles.

Answer (score 7):

You can use getEnv() to get environment variables:

```
String variable = System.getenv("WINDIR");  
System.out.println(variable);
```

I believe the getEnv() function was deprecated at some point but then "undeprecated" later in java 1.5

ETA:

I see the question now refers specifically to java 1.4, so this wouldn't work for you (or at least you might end up with a deprecation warning).  I'll leave the answer here though in case someone else stumbles across this question and is using a later version.

Comment: This is 'the answer' for modern Java versions.  Thanks!

Comment: Deprecated doesn't prevent you from using it ; )

Comment: This will not work on a "recent" Java 1.4 VM which will throw an exception: "java.lang.Error: getenv no longer supported, use properties and -D instead".

Answer (score 4):

There's a switch to the JVM for this. From [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0150.html):

> Start the JVM with the "-D" switch to pass properties to the application 
>   and read them with the System.getProperty() method.

```
SET myvar=Hello world
SET myothervar=nothing
java -Dmyvar="%myvar%" -Dmyothervar="%myothervar%" myClass
```

> then in myClass

```
String myvar = System.getProperty("myvar");
String myothervar = System.getProperty("myothervar");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass them into the JVM as -D system properties, for example:

```
java -D<java var>=%<environment var>%
```

That way you don't become tied to a particular OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
     System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Exec provides with "org.apache.commons.exec.environment.EnvironmentUtils" a way to get the environment variables on JDK's prior 1.5:

```
(String) EnvironmentUtils.getProcEnvironment().get("SOME_ENV_VAR")
```